# Exponential Regression for Parametric Equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, fitting, parametric-functions

I have a few fairly complex parametric equations that describe a linear-log 2D graph which is unable to be described simply (in non-parameterized format). For various ease of calculation purposes, where the extra precision is not needed, I'd like to convert this to a simple (exponential) equation via regression. How would I be able to do this?

As example equations,

$x(t) = \frac{\ln t}{\lceil t \rceil} + 32$

$y(t) = 2^{\ln \lceil t \rceil}$

I can convert it into a plot by using `ParametricPlot[{g, r}, {x, 0, 250000000}, AspectRatio -> 1]` although if I run this plot through `NonlinearModelFit[plot, a x^b + c, {a, b, c}, x]`, I get the error that *First argument `plot` in NonlinearModelFit is not a list or a rectangular array*

Comment: Without an example data set, the most I could suggest is look at `NonlinearModelFit` in the documentation.

Comment: I recommend editing the post to include more information. Can you provide a small sample dataset along with the equations you’re trying to fit? Is it possible to show an example of the kind of output you expect? The less work we have to do, the more likely you are to get an answer, and that answer will be more likely to be what you’re looking for. If you have data generated by your parametric equation you’re trying to fit, I’d recommend taking a look at `LinearModelFit` or  `NonlinearModelFit`. Without more info, it’s hard to say what to do after that.

Comment: @eyorble I tried to do that (`NonlinearModelFit[plot, a x^b + c, {a, b, c}, x]`) and got the response "_first argument `plot` in NonlinearModelFit is not a list or a rectangular array_". I will try to post a couple example equations

Comment: @MassDefect Updated with the info

Comment: @kpm41865zzrgg you can’t fit a plot, you need the data points values, which you could create with Table from your equations, or extract from the plot.

Comment: @MarcoB How would I derive the table from parametric equations? I have been reading through the documentation and cannot find anything besides 1 equation tables. I tried looking up conversion from plots to tables, but all of the answers I can find are on the opposite (table to plot).

Comment: @kpm41865zzrgg Something like `Table[{Log[t]/Ceiling[t] + 32, 2^Log[Ceiling[t]]}, {t, 0, 20, 0.1}]`. Adjust the range and step of $t$ as appropriate. Also I assume that the “half square bracket” notation meant `Ceiling`. If not, fix that to whatever that is supposed to be :-)

Comment: @MarcoB Ah that makes sense. Is there any way to space points logarithmically rather than a `0.1` or whatever number spacing (given that it is lin-log)?

Comment: `PowerRange` might help if you need a logarithmic iterator.

Comment: @MassDefect I tried `Table[{Log[t]/Ceiling[t] + 32, 2^Log[Ceiling[t]]}, {t, {PowerRange[1, 2^32 + 1, 2]}}]` yet I get the `Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 1000000.` reached while evaluating ...` error and the table seems to get messed up, where it displays many numbers seperated by commas but does not denote different sets (ex. `{{{1., 1., 1.33333, 2., 3.2, 5.33333, 9.14286, 16., 28.4444, 51.2, 
   93.0909, 170.667, 315.077, 585.143, 1092.27, 2048., 3855.06, 
   7281.78}, {1., 2., 
   3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.,
    18., 19.}}}`

Comment: It would also help if the sample equations you present have unknown parameters.  Otherwise, there's no reason to perform a regression.

Comment: @JimB The reason for the regression is simply for ease of calculation. The extra precision is not required and the actual equations are *significantly* more complex than the example ones, which makes even most simple computations unwieldy

Comment: But if you have no unknown parameters, there's nothing for the regression to do.  You need to give at least a simple example of what you want.  The example given has $x$, $y$, and $t$.  The `ParametricPlot` statement has $g$, $r$, and $x$.  (And if $y=g$, $x=r$, and $t->x$, then with the range of values '{x, 0, 250000000}`, the log of zero is taken.  I understand the real equations are more complex but you need to give a internally consistent simplified example in which a regression is appropriate (i.e., estimating unknown constants from data).

Comment: I believe the issue with the `PowerRange` example is that you do not need the curly braces around `PowerRange`. It will "generate" its own set of curly braces. Although, I still don't get the error message you have even when I run your code directly. I would expect it to return exact numbers where the precision is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers involved with these equations are definitely a bit tricky, and if your real equations are more complex it will no doubt take some playing around to find the correct parameters. So I'll show you my general process.

First, I generate some data and define a model. I exclude 0 here because it generates infinity.

```
x[t_] := Log[t]/Ceiling[t] + 32
y[t_] := 2^Log[Ceiling[t]]
model[t_, a_, b_, c_] := a (t - 32)^b + c
data = Table[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 1000000, 2500000000, 1000000}];
```

Then, I try to see if I can play around with the parameters using `Manipulate`. This allows me to make some guesses and refine the parameters before calling the fitting routine. It's always a good idea to provide the fitting routine with as many constraints and starting guesses as possible.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPlot[
   data,
   PlotRange -> Full,
   PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5]
   ],
  Plot[
   model[t, a, b, c],
   {t, 32, 32.00001},
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotRange -> {0, 3.5*^6},
   PlotStyle -> Black
   ]
  ],
 {{a, 1}, 1, 10},
 {{b, -0.7}, -1, 0},
 {{c, 14417}, 1000, 1000000}
 ]
```

[image: Manipulate]

At the bottom of the `Manipulate` we have things like `{{a, 1}, 1, 10}`. This says that the value of `a` defaults to 1 and is allowed to range from 1 to 10. It took me a few guesses to find reasonable starting values, and actually I set the default `b` value to -0.7 after finding a fit, though I wasn't all that far off with my original guess.

Now that I have starting values, I'll try a fit and plot the result:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, 
  {a (t - 32)^d + c, {0 < a < 10000000, -1 <= d < 0}}, 
  {{a, 100}, {d, -0.1}, {c, 1000}}, t, MaxIterations -> 2000]

Show[
 ListPlot[
  data,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5]
  ],
 Plot[
  nlm[t],
  {t, 32, 32.0001},
  PlotRange -> Full,
  PlotStyle -> Black
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Plot of fit]

I do get a warning from the fit saying that it hasn't converged, but the fit looks okay on a linear plot, and mostly okay on log/log, log/linear, and linear/log plots. You may have to add an extra parameter to the model. For example, I'm subtracting 32 from `t` in the model, but maybe this should actually be a fitted parameter.

I think there will be some judgements you'll have to make when fitting your real equations, but hopefully this will help you get started.